# Java Series of number of loop

Tags: java, while-loop, logical-operators

Here is my code it doesn't seem to perform the code when n > 0 sout.you entered a positive number, Or i think i'm doing it wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class speed  {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
int num;
int neg = 0, count = 0, pos = 0;

System.out.println("Enter any number to continue. Enter 0 to stop : ");
num = x.nextInt();

if(num==0){
System.out.print("You immediately stop");
System.exit(0);
}

while (num != 0) {
    count ++;
    if (num > 0 ) {
        pos ++;
    } 
    if (num < 0 ) {
        neg ++;

    }
     num = x.nextInt();
    if(count==1){
   }
}
if(count == 1 && num > 0) {

        System.out.print("You entered a positive number");

    if(count ==1 && num < 0) {
        System.out.print("You entered a negative number"); // this code is not performing why?
     } 
System.exit(0);
}  
System.out.printf("You Entered %d numbers\n",count);
System.out.printf("%d positive \n",pos);
System.out.printf("%d negative\n",neg);
}
}
```

Here is the outputs that i have which is correct.

```
My output
Enter a number to continue. Enter 0 to stop :
5
6
-8
0               // doesn't count as a number.
You entered 3 numbers.
2 positive
1 negative
```

BUT in this problem i want the output to be different if the user only typed 1 number.

```
 What i want the output to be >
 Enter a number to continue. Enter 0 to stop :
 2
 0
 You Entered a positive number. // same with a negative number?
```

Comment: You're checking if `num < 0` inside the if-block that checks if `num > 0`.  `num` can't be both positive and negative.

Comment: 0 is postive, so should count for that like num>-1

Comment: @NoorNawaz It works , for the positive number but when i input -2 and 0 it still gives me "you entered a positive number" why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you exit from the while loop, 'num' is always zero. Therefore the test

```
if(count == 1 && num > 0)
```

always fails. Try

```
if(count == 1) {
    if (pos > 0) {
        System.out.print("You entered a positive number");
    } else {
         System.out.print("You entered a negative number");
    }
} else {
    //...put the code for more than one number here
}
```

Also the lines

```
if(count==1){
}
```

do nothing.

Comment: What condition should i use then?

Comment: Written in the answer. You have to think about what it is you are trying to test.

Comment: It is right but the output for neg numbers is wrong

Comment: the out put when i input -2 and 0 is you entered 
1 numbers
0 positive 
1 negative
it needs to be "You entered a negative number but i can't seem to get it.

Comment: What I recommend is that you get a piece of paper. Then mentally step through each line of code, at each line updating the value of each variable on the paper as you go. Do that for a run with one positive number, a run with one negative number, and a run with more than one number. That should pretty quickly tell you what you are doing wrong. If you have access to a debugger, use that.

Comment: I don't have any of that i'm new to the programming itself i didn't come from a programming language i'm just using notepad and cmd.

Comment: You have a piece of paper. If you have the ability to compile Java, you have a Java debugger: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html

Comment: Ohhh i put i tried that but with else if structure lol anyways it works now i didn't think that putting an else for the more than number would work

Comment: No problem. Please vote up and accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score -2):

You could try the below code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class speed  {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
int num;
int neg = 0, count = 0, pos = 0;

System.out.println("Enter any number to continue. Enter 0 to stop : ");
num = x.nextInt();

if(num==0){
System.out.print("You immediately stop");
System.exit(0);
}

while (num != 0) {
    count ++;
    if (num > 0 ) {
        pos ++;
    } 
    if (num < 0 ) {
        neg ++;

    }
     num = x.nextInt();
    if(count==1){
   }
}
if(count == 1 && num > 0) {

        System.out.print("You entered a positive number");

    if(count ==1 && num < 0) {
        System.out.print("You entered a negative number");
     } 
System.exit(0);
}  

  System.out.println("You Entered "+pos+" positive numbers");
  System.out.println("You Entered "+neg+" negative numbers");
}
}
```